# Docker-Compose build failing on Google App Engine

Tags: node.js, git, google-app-engine, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to get my backend up and running on Google App engine, but I am running into some issues with the install.

My backend uses Docker and Docker-compose to install everything and when running

```
docker-compose build
```

it will start to run then stop at

```
npm info git [ 'submodule', '-q', 'update', '--init', '--recursive' ]
```

with the error

```
npm ERR! git submodule -q update --init --recursive: fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
npm ERR! git submodule -q update --init --recursive: github.com[0: 192.30.253.112]: errno=Connection timed out
npm ERR! git submodule -q update --init --recursive: 
npm ERR! git submodule -q update --init --recursive: Clone of 'git://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig-core-test.git' into submodule path 'tests' failed
npm ERR! git submodule -q update --init --recursive: 
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.12
npm ERR! Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v5.12.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.6
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! Command failed: git submodule -q update --init --recursive
npm ERR! fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
npm ERR! github.com[0: 192.30.253.112]: errno=Connection timed out
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Clone of 'git://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig-core-test.git' into submodule path 'tests' failed
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npm-debug.log
ERROR: Service 'Gworker' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c cd /tmp && npm install' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

But this works fine on my local system. The next question is, should I even be using Google App Engine for this, or would Container Engine or Compute Engine be better.